# Form save reference id like NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm new in rails, and I have te below scenario:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
end

class CreateQuizzes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quizzes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|      
      t.text :question
      t.references :quiz, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then when I try to create a new question using simple_form, it's working but save the object question in the database with the quiz_id like NULL, here is the controller and the simple_form that I'm using:

```
//CONTROLLER
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question].permit!)
    if @question.save
      redirect_to quiz_path(@quiz)
    else
      redirect_to error_path
    end
  end

end

//RESOURCES
resources :quizzes do
  resources :questions
end


//VIEW
= simple_form_for([@quiz, @quiz.questions.build]) do |f|
  .container
      .form-group
        = f.input :question, :placeholder => "Question..."
      .submit
        = f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-default"
```

How can create this form and save the questions objects with the correct quiz_id reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `question` hash in `params`does not include `quiz_id`, though `params` does include this information outside that hash.

You can do:

```
@quiz = Quiz.new(params[quiz_id])
@question = @quiz.questions.new(params[:question].permit!)
```

This will also save you from redirecting nowhere in `redirect_to quiz_path(@quiz)`, since `@quiz` is not defined in this action, and variables do not get saved between actions.

By the way, it is useful to add this line to your `layouts/application.html.haml` so you can see the params hash: `=debug(params) if Rails.env.development?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell rails which quiz you want to the question to belong to explicitly in your controller. Rails does not like to assume how you want to handle data.

```
@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id]
@question = @quiz.questions.new(params[:question.permit!)
```